# task list in C++ (vector with more than one type)

Tags: c++, oop

My aim is to fill a list of task; each will be an object containing the description of the task. Let'say there will be only two type of tasks : file copy and repertory copy.

Since a vector cannot contain more than one type of objects, I though to create a generic task class and two classes that inheritate from that one.

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GenericTask{
    public :
        string config;
    GenericTask(string s){
        config=s;
    }
    void run(){
       cout<<"Running generic task" <<endl;
    }
};

class FileCopyTask : public GenericTask{
    public: 
        string filename;
    FileCopyTask(string cf,string fn):GenericTask(cf)
    {
        filename=fn;
    }
    void run(){
        cout<<"file :"<<filename<<endl;
    }
};

class RepertoryCopyTask : public GenericTask{
    public: 
        string repname;
    RepertoryCopyTask(string cf,string rn):GenericTask(cf)
    {
        repname=rn;
    }
    void run(){
        cout<<"repertory : "<<repname<<endl;
    }
};

void run_next(deque<GenericTask> &task_list){
    task_list.front().run();
    task_list.pop_front();
}


int main()
{
    RepertoryCopyTask rtask("configuration","/home");
    FileCopyTask ftask( "configutation","gile.tex" );

    deque<GenericTask> task_list;
    task_list.push_back(rtask);
    task_list.push_back(ftask);
    run_next(task_list);
}
```

As it, it does not work because `run_next`  expect a `GenericTask` and both `rtask` and `ftask` are treated as generic.

How should I do ?

I already tried to add `template` here and there, but ultimately it does not work because I need to know the type inside the `deque` before to "extract" something.

Can I consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663106/collection-of-objects-of-more-than-one-type) as an answer ?

Comment: Maybe you will be interested by this video https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil. Sean parent explains a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create objects of `FileCopyTask` and `RepertoryCopyTask` and save them as pointers to `GenericTask`? This way you can leverage the power of runtime polymorphism.

Like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<GenericTask> ftask = std::make_unique<FileCopyTask>("configutation","gile.tex");
    std::unique_ptr<GenericTask> rtask = std::make_unique<FileCopyTask>("configuration","/home");
    ...
}

void run_next(deque<std::unique_ptr<GenericTask> > &task_list)
{
    ....
}
```

Also, do not forget to mark the `run()` method in class `GenericTask` as `virtual`. Also provide a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: This is running as as I wish, following the example of @umut. I'm now learning the meaning of `virtual`, `unique_ptr` etc. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in your source. Defined your base fn as virtual and stored objects with pointers. You can check it below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GenericTask{
    public :
        string config;
    GenericTask(string s){
        config=s;
    }
    virtual void run(){
       cout<<"Running generic task" <<endl;
    }
};

class FileCopyTask : public GenericTask{
    public: 
        string filename;
    FileCopyTask(string cf,string fn):GenericTask(cf)
    {
        filename=fn;
    }
    void run(){
        cout<<"file :"<<filename<<endl;
    }
};

class RepertoryCopyTask : public GenericTask{
    public: 
        string repname;
    RepertoryCopyTask(string cf,string rn):GenericTask(cf)
    {
        repname=rn;
    }
    void run(){
        cout<<"repertory : "<<repname<<endl;
    }
};

void run_next(deque<GenericTask*> &task_list){
    task_list.front()->run();
    task_list.pop_front();
}


int main()
{
    RepertoryCopyTask* rtask = new RepertoryCopyTask("configuration","/home");
    FileCopyTask* ftask = new FileCopyTask( "configutation","gile.tex" );

    deque<GenericTask*> task_list;
    task_list.push_back(ftask);
    task_list.push_back(rtask);
    run_next(task_list);
}
```

Comment: ok. So instead of creating a `deque` of two types objects, we build a `deque` of only one type : pointers. The point which is still obscure to me is that `deque<GenericTask*> task_list` makes that `task_list` is a list of pointers that are intended to point to `GenericTask` objects. In the `run_next` function, `task_list` is expected to be a `GenericTask` (pointer) list. Why `task_list.front()` does extract a `FileCopyTask` ? Maybe I need a course about pointers ...

Comment: If you are not so familiar with pointers, you should read something about them. In our case `task_list.front()` is returning a `GenericTask` object not `FileCopyTask` object. That's very important. Base pointers only knows its own functions and variables. But we put a special keyword to our base run function, `virtual`. When we try to reach base object's run method, it sees `virtual` keyword and tries to find the most derived class and uses its function. That's why `task_list.front()->run()` found `FileCopyTask` object's run method. Hope i could explained

Comment: It makes sense. I'll definitively read something about pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I do ?

Consider these steps:

- define GenericTask as a base class (add virtual destructor, make `void run` virtual)
- override the run function in derived classes
- store elements in the queue as std::unique_ptr, instead of "by value" to avoid the slicing problem.

> I already tried to add template here and there, but ultimately it does not work because I need to know the type inside the deque before to "extract" something.

You can add a boost::variant as the value, allowing the storage of unrelated types.

> Can I consider this [this=answer proposing boost::any as value type] as an answer ?

Yes. boost::variant would be similar (the difference is that boost::any supports setting *any* value; boost::variant only supports values of the types provided as variant arguments).

Answer (score -1):

A classical case of `virtual`. The run methods need to be declared `virtual` s.t. you are actually calling RepertoryCopyTask::run() on an object of type GenericTask.

When done correctly,

```
FileCopyTask t("a", "b");
GenericTask & g = t;
g.run();
```

will call `FileCopyTask::run` instead of `GenericTask::run` (which it would in the original question).

When you did this, you can't store your `FileCopyTask`s and `RepertoryCopyTask` in a contaianer for `GenericTask`. This is because they might even have different size. To get around this, you should store `unique_ptr`s for them in some container, i.e.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GenericTask> > tasks;
```

This would be the correct way of solving your problem.

Comment: Wrong answer. The deque only stores `GenericTask`. Virtual is needed when pointers are used.

Comment: No? Pointer or not doesn't matter. The problem is, that no matter what you have stored previously, always the `GenericTask::run` will be used. To change that, you will need virtual lookup (ie. ask what kind of `run` method is to be used). As a consequence, the storage of the `GenericTask`s will have to be changed.

Comment: Explanation of my first sentence: If you have a `deque<GenericTask>`, and you use `push_back()` on it, the object gets copy-constructed. At this point, whatever type the given object was, the newly-constructed object is always a `GenericTask`. Explanation of my second sentence: The `virtual` keyword is only needed for late binding. But if you construct an object of a derived class, early binding is used. Late binding is only needed if you have a pointer to a base class.

Comment: Both is trivial and true. Neither answers the question, neither justifies my answer to be wrong.

Comment: You should work on your attitude. After our previous comments, you heavily edited your answer to make it both more relevant and correct. Then you say my comments, which were crucial to you improving an initially bad answer, are "trivial". Whatever.